# correlated binomial distribution in r

Tags: r, correlation

i want to generate a second vector in r which is correlated to my first vector.
the first vector is simply created as following:

```
x <- rbinom(n=10,1,p=0.8)
x
[1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

my second vector should be generated with a defined correlation e.g. 0.8.
i know that you can use mvrnorm() for the normal distribution, but i dont know how to do it for the binomial distribution. i tried to find some solution but the suggestions were a bit too complicated for me or i could not apply to my code.

Comment: Have you seen this existing answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/generating-correlated-binomial-random-variables Can you be more clear on what you tried and where exactly you got stuck? What parts specifically were complicated?

Comment: yes i saw this . the problem is that i do not come from this area. i do a lot of data analysis so this topic is new to me. i found it difficult to understand the mathematical principles behind this. I saw that some suggest to use copula and some suggestions work but they generate the two variables at the same time. In my case i do not want to generate two variables because i already have one vector with the data i generated. So i like to generate the second vector in a separate step. so i find it hard to use the suggestions for similar cases for my problem

Comment: Then that's not really a straightforward thing to do. You'll need to get statistical advice first from [stats.se] to find a data simulation strategy that would be appropriate. Then you can figure out how to do it in R.

Answer (score 0):

I second the recommendation that you visit [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). It is not clear how you are planning to use the correlated binomial distribution. Given your stipulation that you are starting with one vector and you want to create a second based on the first, all you need to do is adjust the probabilities of the second vector:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rbinom(n=1000, size=1, p=0.8)      # Your first vector
y <- rbinom(n=1000, size=1, p=ifelse(x==1, .95, .05))
cor(x, y)
# [1] 0.8505885
y <- rbinom(n=1000, size=1, p=ifelse(x==1, .94, .06))
cor(x, y)   
# [1] 0.821918
y <- rbinom(n=1000, size=1, p=ifelse(x==1, .93, .07))
cor(x, y)
# [1] 0.7679597
```

In generating the second vector, the probability for the second vector is greater than .8 (the probability of a 1) if the value is 1 in the first vector and less than .2 (the probability of a 0) if the value is 0 in the first vector.

Comment: Yes this is a way i already had in mind but my struggle with this solution is that i can't set the correlation in the beginning like i want. I plan on using the correlated binomial distribution to simulate a scenario where two diagnostic test exist. I want to add a correlation between those two tests. It is like: i generate vector one as my first test sample. next i would do the second test with the same "people" and this is my second vector. of course the two test should have correlation.